# Type Classes When Implementing HFoldr

Tags: haskell, hlist

I'm trying to implement `HFoldr` for a simple case where you apply an `Endo a` to the first `a` in the `HList`. The code looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Lib
    ( x2, z3
    ) where

import Data.HList
import Data.Monoid

x2 :: HList '[Sum Integer, String, Sum Integer, String]
x2 = 3 .*. "Hello" .*. 4 .*. " World" .*. HNil

data HUpdateFirst = HUpdateFirst

instance (HOccursNot a l, r ~ (HList l)) => HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) l r where
  hFoldr _ _ l = l
instance (r ~ (HList (a ': l))) => HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) (a ': l) r where
  hFoldr _ f (HCons v l) = HCons (appEndo f v) l
instance (HOccurs a (HList l), r ~ (HList (b ': l)), HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) l (HList l))
    => HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) (b ': l) r where
  hFoldr h f (HCons v l) = HCons v (hFoldr h f l)

z3 :: HList '[Sum Integer, String, Sum Integer, String]
z3 = hFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo (++ " X ")) x2
```

If I exclude `z3`, the code compiles, but when I actually put `z3` in, I get

`No instance for (Fail (TypeFound [Char]))
      arising from a use of ‘hFoldr’
    In the expression: hFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo (++ " X ")) x2
    In an equation for ‘z3’:
        z3 = hFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo (++ " X ")) x2`

As far as I can tell, this is saying that it can't figure out what to do if `String` isn't in the list, but a) it is and b) that's what the first clause is meant to be for.

I suspect that my problem may lie in not understanding Haskell's inference rules better, so any pointers on that subject would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but do have one observation: I notice that all your instances are of the form `HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) x (HList x)`, with `x` ranging over `l` ,`a ': l`, and `b ': l`. The amount of overlap in these values for `x` is extremely worrying to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extremely limited version of the answer is that `HOccurs` seems to be causing problems.  The following code works:

`instance (HOccursNot a l, r ~ HList l) => HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) l r where
  hFoldr _ _ l = l
instance (r ~ HList (a ': l)) => HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) (a ': l) r where
  hFoldr _ f (HCons a r) = HCons (appEndo f a) r
instance (r ~ HList (b ': l), HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) l (HList l))
    => HFoldr HUpdateFirst (Endo a) (b ': l) r where
  hFoldr h f (HCons v l) = HCons v (hFoldr h f l)`